# Android Studio Error:Could not normalize path for file. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I got err in the android studio

`Error:Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\rajesh.vijayakumar\AndroidStudioProjects\UserEventDemo\tv\build\intermediates\mockable-Google Inc.:Google APIs:21.jar'.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

Can anybody know how to resolve this error in android studio..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the Android Gradle plugin version to 1.1.2:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
}
```

This release contains the fix of [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=148912) of improper escape of illegal characters on Windows machines.